# I'm doing a PHP login page taking posted vars and putting in mysql_connect params. Is it a bad practice?

Tags: php, authentication, mysql-connect

first of all, thanks for your time. Like the subject says... i'm doing a login page, but every search send me to the same code:

```
use posted user & pass
connect to mysql
search for the user & pass posted
if returns records then ok 
else bad access
```

but i'm doing this way (and i hope some one can tell me if i'm doing it wrong and why)

```
session_start();
$user=$_POST['user'];
$pass=$_POST['password'];
$link=mysql_connect('localhost',$user,$pass);
if(!link){
   echo "Access denied";
}else{
   echo "Access OK";
   $_SESSION['user']=$user;
   $_SESSION['password']=$password;
}
```

And each time i need to verify if user is logged in, i do the same connecting to mysql. Is there here the posibility of code injection? (Like Sql Injection, PHP script or anything else) Is this a bad practice? is there any risk?

BTW, this works fine for me but i want to put it on internet and i don't want to be hacked. Thanks

Comment: Every user in your app has his own login credentials to your MySQL server? I don't think that this is what you wanted.

Comment: Fox, you should not blindly use user input. This, IMHO, really is not a good practice. In my books it is written as, "Thy shalt not trust user input."

Comment: That's what PHPMysqlAdmin and other tools do. But I guess you should whitelist/restrict the allowable usernames and characters for the password still. (Really unsure if that's binary-safe in the mysql_ API. At least *null bytes* could pose a problem.)

Comment: Has anyone of the people answering even read the question?

Comment: @cularis Obviously not. Just brutal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code as it stands is not vulnerable to SQL injection, despite what the other answers say. The reason is that you're seriously misusing SQL.

Your database credentials and your user's credentials should *not* be the same thing. Your database username/password should be a secret shared between your PHP script and your database. Typically you would then create a `users` table *within* the database, and store your user records there. This is why the tutorials you mention `select` a user record and compare the password - there are multiple user records stored inside the database as data in a table.

With your current system, you will have to create a new database user for each and every user of your system. This is going to be an administrative nightmare and introduces a whole bunch of new security troubles.

Comment: This is what i wanted to read =) Thanks for say the reason why i'm not doing it right. I see some PHP script that encrypt password and store it in user table and when the user is going to login, the password is encripted and compared with the stored. I think this is the right way (obviously using functions like mysql_real_escape_string to avoid the SQL injection). Still i can't imagine why it could be an administrative nightmare but it's cos i'm not measuring the whole thing, i guess. For the rest i see the point, the mysql user information is a secret, thanks =D

Answer (score -2):

rather than $_POST['password'] you should write mysql_real_escape_string ($_POST['password']) and like wise for all post variables to avoid sql injection and strip_tags($_POST['password']) to strip all html tags and php tags ..

by this you can strengthen your security..

Comment: *NO NO NO*. `strip_tags` is *not* used this way. You don't need to prevent HTML from entering your database. This doesn't add security, it potentially breaks your system. If I want to use `my<i>pass</i>` as a password, so what? Blindly implementing broken security is just as bad as implementing no security at all.